# IP address whitelisting for specific service

Tags: networking, iptables, whitelist

How do you filter external connections to a specific service, running on Docker?  Specifically, how do you filter incoming requests down to a static list of whitelisted IPs?

Comment: Why don't you use `iptables` for that, especially if the published port is static?

Comment: I can try that. I'm not familiar with configuring iptables on ubuntu but I can look into it if that's the proper way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Are you running the CaaS (Container as a Service) on a specific static port?

Comment: I'm really not sure. We are using IBM's Bluemix to host the containers. I assumed there would be an easy way to do this either in a Docker file or some other way. I'm exploring iptables now. Seems like a reasonable option.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that:

- The container will always listen on the same host:port.
- The container will always be bound on the same network card interface, if ever several are available. This is easily done by using the option `-p hostIp:hostPort:containerPort` within the `docker run` command.

Stemming from these two assumptions, it can then be assumed that the service running in the container will always listen on the same host socket defined as `hostIp:hostPort`.

---

Now, all you have to do is *firewalling* which is independent from docker.

*I am not an expert and did not test theses lines! Be warned before executing them.*

```
# DROP every packets coming from every sources sent to the port $PORT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORT -j DROP
# ACCEPT every packets coming from source xx.xx.xx.xx sent to port $PORT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s xx.xx.xx.xx --dport $PORT -j ACCEPT
# Repeat the last command if needed, you can also specify a network, such as 192.30.252.0/22 instead of xx.xx.xx.xx
```

These rules are to be set in this precise order. A whitelist can be likened to a blacklist with expection.